# Copy new data into other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have one worksheet called `mainData`, which contains all data for ten products.

When I enter new data in `mainData`, I want to automatically copy the new data into the last row of another product worksheet. When I enter new data into `mainData`, how can I recognize the new data belongs to which product's worksheet, hence copy the new data into the product worksheet?

I'm stuck in copying it to another worksheet because I need to copy it to another ten worksheets according to product's type.

Here's what I've done to the `mainData`:

```
With Sheets("mainData")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Range("B" & LastRow) = ComboBox1.Text
    .Range("C" & LastRow) = TextBox1.Text
    .Range("D" & LastRow) = TextBox2.Text
    .Range("E" & LastRow) = TextBox3.Text
    .Range("F" & LastRow) = TextBox4.Text
    .Range("G" & LastRow) = TextBox5.Text
    .Range("H" & LastRow) = ComboBox2.Text
    .Range("I" & LastRow) = TextBox6.Text
    .Range("J" & LastRow) = TextBox7.Text
    .Range("K" & LastRow) = TextBox8.Text


    Range("B32:B320").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mainData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mainData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B32:B305") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4, prod5, prod6, prod7, prod8, prod9, prod10" _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mainData").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B32:W305")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

here's what i mean.when i enter new prod1 data into mainData worksheet, i want to automatically copy it into the last row of product 1 worksheet. i may enter many type of product i.e prod2,prod4 into mainData so how to copy this data into its particular product worksheet?

Comment: `how can I recognize the new data belongs to which product's worksheet,` Er, you will have to tell us that(at least in logic) how to differentiate. Which field is the `Product type` and how is it related to a particular worksheet i.e does the worksheet name is an indicator of the product type or is it something else? Maybe you could also give us an example?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes the worksheet name is an indicator of the product type. if the product type is prod2 means i need to copy it to worksheet product 2.

Comment: So Col `B` will have the product code?

Comment: yes. each product have different product code.

Comment: Two more questions. `1` will there be only prod1-10? `2` Do you need to add it to `mainData` or directly add it to the relevant sheet?

Comment: yes.means at mainData i only can enter prod1-10 but with different product code.i need to enter new data at mainData first then automatically update it into relevant sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

Also I have not done any error handling. I am sure you will take care of it :)

```
Dim prd As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'~~> Extract the number from the combobox
prd = Trim(Replace(ComboBox1.Text, "prod", ""))

'~~> Decide which sheet the data needs to be written to
'~~> Please ensure that sheets have names like "Product 1", "Product 2" etc
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product " & prd)

'~~> Update it to the relevant sheet
With ws
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Range("B" & LastRow) = ComboBox1.Value
    .Range("C" & LastRow) = TextBox1.Text
    .Range("D" & LastRow) = TextBox2.Text
    .Range("E" & LastRow) = TextBox3.Text
    .Range("F" & LastRow) = TextBox4.Text
    .Range("G" & LastRow) = TextBox5.Text
    .Range("H" & LastRow) = ComboBox2.Value
    .Range("I" & LastRow) = TextBox6.Text
    .Range("J" & LastRow) = TextBox7.Text
    .Range("K" & LastRow) = TextBox8.Text

    '~~> Sort the data
    With .Range("B2:W" & LastRow)
        .Sort Key1:=ws.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End With

'~~> Update it in mainData
With Sheets("mainData")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Range("B" & LastRow) = ComboBox1.Value
    .Range("C" & LastRow) = TextBox1.Text
    .Range("D" & LastRow) = TextBox2.Text
    .Range("E" & LastRow) = TextBox3.Text
    .Range("F" & LastRow) = TextBox4.Text
    .Range("G" & LastRow) = TextBox5.Text
    .Range("H" & LastRow) = ComboBox2.Value
    .Range("I" & LastRow) = TextBox6.Text
    .Range("J" & LastRow) = TextBox7.Text
    .Range("K" & LastRow) = TextBox8.Text

    '~~> Sort the data
    With .Range("B2:W" & LastRow)
        .Sort Key1:=Sheets("mainData").Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End With
```

Comment: thanks.yes it works for product sheets.actually what i want to do is copy into another workbooks, not into sheets in same workbooks.anyway thanks for helping.i'm really new into vba.still blurr on how to links the workbooks

Comment: I just went through your question again. Where have you mentioned that you have to copy it to the worksheets in the other workbooks?

Comment: i'm really sorry.just realize that i don't mention it.yes i want to copy it to worksheet in the other workbooks.my mistake